# Why isn't my parent component updating the view when I change the variables through child function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

**The Problem**

When I click on the button in the child I do run the function in the parent and the variables do flip flop from true to false but the components in the main LoginView do not rotate...it is always stuck on the TheLogin component... never switching to the TheRegister. The Console logs show that the variables are changing values as expected..

**The parent**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import TheLogin from '../components/TheLogin.vue'
import TheRegister from '../components/TheRegister.vue'

var login = true;
var register = false;

const dotoggle = (thevalue) => {
    console.log(login);
    console.log(register);
    login = login ? false : true;
    register = register ? false : true;
    login = false;
}
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <TheLogin v-if="login" @togglereg="dotoggle" />
    <TheRegister v-if="register" />
  </main>
</template>
```

**the CHILD**

```
<script setup lang="ts">


const emits = defineEmits(["togglereg"])

</script>

<template>
  <div class="carorbitalhead">CARORBITAL</div>
    <div><input class="inputmain" type="text" placeholder="username" /></div>
    <div><input class="inputmain" type="password" placeholder="password" /></div>
    <div><button class="buttonmain">SIGN IN</button></div>
    <div><button @click.prevent="$emit('togglereg','4')" class="buttonmain">REGISTER</button></div>
    <div>-- OR --</div>
    <div>SOCIAL LOGINS</div>
</template>
```

Comment: your `login` and `register` variables aren't reactive.  The template won't update until they're defined as such using `ref` function.  See [Vue Reactivity documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables aren't reactive so the template in the parent component isn't updated, use refs:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import {ref} from 'vue';

import TheLogin from '../components/TheLogin.vue'
import TheRegister from '../components/TheRegister.vue'

var login = ref(true);
var register = ref(false);

const dotoggle = () => {
    register.value = true;
    login.value = false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there were issues with the logic in the parent's toggle function and the value of the child component.

The parent component switches between two child components (TheLogin and TheRegister) based on the values of login and register variables.

Now the parent's dotoggle function was simplified to correctly toggle between login and register variables.

**Parent Component:**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import TheLogin from '../components/TheLogin.vue'
import TheRegister from '../components/TheRegister.vue'

var login = true;
var register = false;

const dotoggle = () => {
  login = !login;
  register = !register;
};
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <TheLogin v-if="login" @togglereg="dotoggle" />
    <TheRegister v-if="register" />
  </main>
</template>
```

**Child Component:**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const emits = defineEmits(["togglereg"]);
</script>

<template>
  <div class="carorbitalhead">CARORBITAL</div>
  <div><input class="inputmain" type="text" placeholder="username" /></div>
  <div><input class="inputmain" type="password" placeholder="password" /></div>
  <div><button class="buttonmain">SIGN IN</button></div>
  <div><button @click.prevent="$emit('togglereg')" class="buttonmain">REGISTER</button></div>
  <div>-- OR --</div>
  <div>SOCIAL LOGINS</div>
</template>
```

Hope it will helps you :)